# How to edit lists using input function

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

I am trying to edit and fill the lists in A, B and C using the input function.

```
A = ['']
B = ['']
C = ['']
key = input()
key[0] = 'X'
```

But i get this error.

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How can i use the input function to edit my list. Or you might have better way to do this?

Thank You!

Comment: why are you editing `key` if you want to edit the lists `A`, `B` and `C`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. instead of using lists, better use dictionary to fill the A, B or C.

```
var = {'A':' ', 'B':' ', 'C':' '}
var[input()] = 'X'
```

Thanks for all of your participation!

Answer (score 1):

The `strings` per se in **Python** are immutable (**you can't modify its content**) however what you can do is to store them in a `char list` and a `list` in python is a mutable object, hence you can modify the `char list` as you see fit.

```
key = input() # "hello"
new_key = list(key) # ['h','e','l','l','o']
new_key[0] = 'X' # ['X','e','l','l','o']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings are immutable objects which means you cannot change an existing string. The best you can do is create a new string that is a variation on the original. For e.g :

```
newstring = 'newchar' + oldstring[1:]
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
key = input()
newkey = 'X' +key[1:]
```